# image_lib codeigniter disable image renaming

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, resize

I am using Codeigniter's image_lib library to resize my images, it is working fine but it renames the image as "original_name_thumb.ext". I dont want it to rename it by adding _thumb. I am saving them in new folders. So rename is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set `thumb_marker = "";`

```
$config["thumb_marker"] = "";
```

while setting config for image library and it should work fine. See [docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html)